# Retrieving created_at value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way I could retrieve `created_at` value from the Database in Rails?

The table has columns like `ticket_created`, `ticket_updated`. By default a `created_at` column is also included. If I try doing:

```
  @tickets = Ticket.find(:all)

  for ticket in @tickets
    puts ticket.created_at
  end
```

the above code is returning `ticket_created` instead of the automatically generated `created_at`

The sample database row looks like this.

```
id | title | link | key | summary | priority | status | created_at | updated_at | ticket_created | ticket_updated
```

Comment: Could you please post the code from you `ticket` model? Isn't it possible you have a `created_at` method there?

Comment: The Model code is as is `class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base end` I haven't added anything here. This snippet is from `/models/ticket.rb`

Comment: your `ticket_created` and `created_at` field are not the same ?

Comment: @Shinagra I understand that. But my pain point is why is it returning the `ticket_created` value when i am querying for `created_at` ?

Comment: Out of interest, what does `puts ticket.attributes` return?

Comment: what version of rails are you running?

Comment: @John I am just printing something in the console for test purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to really put yourself at ease that the two columns contain different values.

```
Ticket.find(:all).map {|t|
  {:attributes => t.attributes,
   :created_at => t.created_at,
   :ticket_created => t.ticket_created}
}.inspect
```

Then try `t.created_at == t.ticket_created` to make sure they aren't equal and then lastly, rename the `ticket_created` column to `something_else` and see if that does the trick.